# Python: Efficient way to concatenate permutations of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, permutation

I have a list of strings:

```
words = ["AAAA", "xyzw", "1234"]
```

The end goal is to generate all permutations resulting from concatenating items in `words`, i.e.,

```
"AAAAxyzw1234"
"AAAA1234xyzw"
"xyzwAAAA1234"
"xyzw1234AAAA"
"1234AAAAxyzw"
"1234xyzwAAAA"
```

`words` might be a very long list, each string may be very long in length.

---

Is there a more efficient way to do this than this dumb way below, where I generate each permutation one by one and then `join` them?

```
import itertools

def join_perms(words):
    for perm in itertools.permutations(words):
        yield ''.join(perm)

def main():
    words = ["AAAA"*10, "xyzw"*10, "1234"*10] * 3
    for result in join_perms(words):
        # do something with result
        pass

>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(main, number=100)
10.4355671406
```

The runtime becomes egregious with every append to `words`, since permutations is a `O(n!)` problem.

Comment: I doubt there is a better way in Python, after all isn't this exactly what `permutations` is for?

Comment: Let's assume that there exist a way to write the code that produces one element of this set every nanosecond (note: even if you write directly in assembly you'll probably need several tens of nanoseconds or microsecond to actually do this), then for `n=20` it will take about 77 **years** to produce all the output, more likely a real computer will take some centuries/thousand of years. So: the answer to your question is: if you have to handle O(n!) things you **must** keep `n` incredibly *small*, or just give up.